# dynamically switch (http)s on pages content to secure protocol (javascript)

Tags: javascript, dynamic, https, protocols

I'm going to dynamically change the protocols in source of all pages on Blogger.

Eg All **http://** change to **https://** on below items:

- `<link rel="..." type="..." href="http://www.blogger.com/..." />`
- `<script src="http://www.blogger.com/..."></script>`
- `<iframe src="http://www.blogger.com/..."></iframe>`
- `<a href='http://www.blogger.com/...'></a>`
- And if possible on internal javascript variables

Comment: Why with javascript? I may be missing something but I think you would be much better off with a server-side language for this. Although it can be done, it is not very robust and not as intuitive to do as it would be with php or most any other server-side language.

Comment: @stefgosselin good, but no on the blogger!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best choice for you is using Protocol-Relative aka Protocol-Agnostic urls:

```
<link rel="..." type="..." href="//www.blogger.com/..." />
<script src="//www.blogger.com/..."></script>
<iframe src="//www.blogger.com/..."></iframe>
<a href='//www.blogger.com/...'></a>
```

So no need to change anything dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, but there is not any way to staticly edit these items in blogger!

Comment: How did I not know about this general solution!

Answer (score 1):

You need to approach independently if you dont want to approach the first answer.
Like, changing the body content (better to keep inside a div) and using the javascript function like below on page load event. For script tags which are under head tag you need to load them dynamically using other approaches like we load JSON.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content">
......
....
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function replaceHTTPS()
{
  var oldContent = document.getElementById ("content").innerHTML;
  var newContent = oldContent.replace("http",/https/g);
document.getElementById ("content").innerHTML = newContent;


}
</script>
```

**EDIT**

First clear all the head tag using this code

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML = "";
```

You could use following code to load the script dynamically (needs to store the script names in an static array or read them from head tag before clear)

```
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= 'https://....filenames.js';
   head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is best answer for me! but this cod does not work on head section... can you edit it for do on all sections of page?